# Different Menus on Different Pages

Tags: php, wordpress, header

Trying to have different navigation menus on different pages. My theme doesn't let me edit the functions page. I created a new header template and page template. I want to change the menu used in the new header template, but I don't understand what the code below means so I'm not exactly sure what to change.

I'm trying to learn so could someone help translate what this code means?

```
<ul id="menu-hosting-menu" class="curved">
                    <?php if ( is_page() ) $highlight = 'page_item'; else $highlight = 'page_item 

current_page_item'; ?>
                    <li class="<?php echo $highlight; ?> menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom"><a href="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>">Home</a></li>
                    <?php wp_list_pages( 'sort_column=menu_order&depth=3&title_li=&exclude=' ); ?>
                </ul><!-- /#nav -->
                <?php }  ?>

                 <select> 
                    <option value="" selected="selected">Select</option> 
                    <?php
                    $menu_name = 'primary-menu'; //same as theme_location
                    if ( ( $locations = get_nav_menu_locations() ) && isset( $locations[ 

 $menu_name ] ) ) {
                        $menu = wp_get_nav_menu_object( $locations[ $menu_name ] );
                        $menu_items = wp_get_nav_menu_items($menu->term_id);
                        var_dump($menu_items);
                        foreach ( (array) $menu_items as $key => $menu_item ) {
                            $title = $menu_item->title;
                            $url = $menu_item->url;
                            if($menu_item->menu_item_parent){
                                $title = '-- '.$title;
                            }
                            $menu_list .= '<option value="' . $url . '">' . $title . 

 '</option>'; 
   }} else {
                        $menu_list .= '<option  value="">Menu "' . $menu_name . '" not 

defined.</option>';
                    }
                    echo $menu_list;
                    ?>
                  </select> 



        </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to load the menu on an entirely new template, or just a particular page?

I imagine one (simple) approach to this would be to create both a new page template, and a new header. You would simply then tell the new page template (selectable in your Admin panel in the CMS) to call the new (custom) header as well.

A great explanation on how this can be done is found here:

http://reflectingthedesigner.com/wordpress/2011/10/24/creating-a-new-wordpress-page-template/

Hope this helps.

Comment: That is exactly what I am trying to do. Everything is great except I can't figure out how to use the new custom menu. The code above is from the new header file that the new template uses.  I just want to call a new menu called Hosting. There is all this code in the file (above) and I dont know what it means so I dont know what to change.

Comment: Interesting solution. Can you paste your Hosting header.php code, I'm interested in what you did. Also, apologies that I pretty much just repeated your question. I am an idiot; I misread what you wrote.

Glad it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I just deleted all of that code above and replaced it with

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'Hosting' )); ?>
```

Worked like a charm.